# MySQL - find columns where type = mediumtext and max(char_length)<255

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where we have hit max row size due to excessive columns.

I've found a way to list the columns and the max characters for the type of mediumtext which I intend on converting to varchar(200 or smaller) to reduce the footprint.

I would like to further refine this query to just show any mediumtext that is less than 255 characters.

```
SELECT CONCAT(
GROUP_CONCAT(
CONCAT('(SELECT \'',COLUMN_NAME,'\' AS `column`,MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(`',COLUMN_NAME,'`)) AS `max_length` ','FROM`',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'` ORDER BY `max_length` DESC LIMIT 1)')
SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
), ';'
) AS _SQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'myTable'
AND COLUMN_TYPE='mediumtext';
```

I've been replacing `;` with `order by max_length desc;` to get what I need and then eliminate what I don't want. However, I'd like to pretty it up.

This is the output I'm getting right now.

```
| column                   | max_length |
+--------------------------+------------+
| a_str_7                  |        291 |
| description              |        268 |
| a_str_8                  |        160 |
| a_str_9                  |         93 |
| close_notes              |         46 |
| a_str_6                  |          2 |
| comments                 |       NULL |
| work_notes               |       NULL |
| group_list               |       NULL |
| a_str_10                 |       NULL |
| comments_and_work_notes  |       NULL |
| additional_assignee_list |       NULL |
| user_input               |       NULL |
| a_str_11                 |       NULL |
| work_notes_list          |       NULL |
| approval_history         |       NULL |
| watch_list               |       NULL |
| a_str_12                 |       NULL |
| mgt_only                 |       NULL |
```

Comment: Wow.  It's rare to find an example of busting the 65K row limit (excluding text and blob fields).  Kudos.

Comment: Thanks! I can't take credit as our admins just keep adding columns to the same table instead of creating a new table with relational data. You know, like it's supposed to be...

Comment: You can safely ignore `BLOB` and `TEXT` fields  (`mediumtext`) as they don't contribute significantly to the table limit due to how they're stored.  It's other fields like `varchar`  or `char` that can cause issue--especially if they have arbitrarily large limits.  I see often folk just defaulting to 255 for varchar even just to store staet abbriviations (2 characters in the US).  while varchar doesn't use up much memory more in this case, it does affect the total max row size left as it needs to plan for the larges possible entry.